# Simple data sharing in IBM MobileFirst (in IOS)

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am doing a simple data sharing between 2 apps in IBM MobileFirst in hybrid way. 
Please refer to this:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_enabling_simple_data_sharing_hybrid.html

I had successfully implement in Android.
But for IOS, where to define the "Application ID prefix" ? Doesn't it generated by Xcode automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application ID is managed in the Apple Developer Portal. This is linked to in the user documentation topic you have read:

> For iOS environments, follow these steps. Ensure that applications
>   that are part of the same family share the same Application ID prefix.
>   For more information, see [Managing Multiple App ID Prefixes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html) in the iOS
>   Developer Library.

If you follow the link, it leads you to this Apple user documntation topic:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html

In your Apple Developer portal page, where you create the App ID for your application**s**, you need to make sure that both apps use the same App ID.